# Google Play A/B store listing testing and APK

Tags: android, google-play, ab-testing

I have an Android app and I'm doing some **A/B test experiments** to see how the store listing text performs.

In one of my test I changed the logo image. The problem is that I have the same logo image inside my app, as a resource file. It is shown on the splash screen during loading.

Both **A** and **B** test are serving the same APK of course so it may be confusing for users on **B** to see a given logo on the store listing and then a different one on the actual app.

How can I solve this? I suspect the only option available is to remove the logo image from the APK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem without a definitely correct answer. There are at least two points of view.

The first point of view says "it doesn't matter". A/B store listing  experiments are about seeing which store listing works best to convert a user from "someone who is looking at your listing" to "someone who installs your app". By the time you have got to the splash screen the experiment has done it's job. Yes it is a slightly strange experience for some users, but that's ok. Run the experiment for long enough to get a result about which works best, then change both the store listing and the app to use that icon.

The second point of view says the inconsistency matters. Having an inconsistent icon will make the user confused, lead to higher tech support costs, and more uninstalls. It would be nice to make the icon match, but the trouble is, for any given user you don't know which experiment branch they were in, and Google don't give you any way to find this out. So while it would be nice to have it match you can't. This leaves you with two options:

- take the logo out of the splash screen
- switch to a third logo on the splash screen that is different to both experiment conditions

Personally I think I take the first point of view. But if you take the second, there are at least two things you can do.

Comment: ok thanks, answer accepted. I'll remove the splash screen logo. This way nor A or B will get confused and the test will do its job anyway. I prefer to remove it because I suspect a confused user is worst than not having the logo on the splash screen. No one will write a bad review about a missing logo, but someone may write a bad review about downloading something and being presented with something else. As strange as it may sound, from a user perspective a different logo image means a completely different app

Comment: Have anyone tried loading information about active store listing experiments in the app itself and then determining depending on which variant user gets to load one logo or another?